# Subscribe cancels the subject when the source publisher completes

Tags: swift, reactive-programming, rx-swift, combine

I have a function which receives a `Publisher` and creates a `PassthroughSubject` that is used to both:

1. - subscribe to the source publisher
2. - `send` values manually

E.g.:

```swift
class Adapter<T>{
  let innerSubject=PassThroughSubject<T,Never>()
  let scope = Scope() // custom type, Array<AnyCancellable>
  func init(_ source:Publisher<T,Never>){
    source.register(innerSubject).in(scope)
    innerSubject.sink(receiveValue:{debugPrint($0)}).in(scope)
  }
  func adapt(_ T val){
    innerSubject.send(val)
  }
}

fn usage(){
  let adapter=Adapter(Empty()) // change to Empty(completeImmediately:false) to fix
  adapter.adapt(42) // should print 42,
}
```

The inner subject seems to be cancelled because Empty calls complete.
I would expect the inner subject's *subscription* to be cancelled, not the subject itself. In .Net at least that's the behaviour - am I missing something? Do I need to wrap this in a broadcasting subject? I thought that Publishers could receive multiple Receivers and multicast to each?

Comment: What do you mean by "broadcasting subject"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would expect the inner subject's subscription to be cancelled, not the subject itself. In .Net at least that's the behaviour - am I missing something?

Just like with Observables, when a Publisher emits a completed event, it *will not* emit any more events. A Subject is a kind of Publisher. The behavior is exactly the same as in .Net so I can only assume you are missing something.

> I thought that Publishers could receive multiple Receivers and multicast to each?

Yes they can. But they send the exact same values to each receiver, including the completion event. However, again just like with Observables and Rx Subjects, once it emits a completion event, it cannot emit anything else.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, will make sure that when multicasting, I suppress completion unwanted completion events (here I will send a completion event when the adapter is not needed, rather than when its source completes)

Comment: In Rx, I would just do a `.concat(with: .never())` to suppress the completion event. I'm not sure how to do it in Combine.